# Getting the timestamp of a file using PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, file, plsql, timestamp

I am trying to get the timestamp of a text file abc.txt in some directory XYZ in oracle server. This file can get updated at any time in the day and i have to check if the file was updated any time after yesterday midnight, if yes i need to email that file as an attachment.

Is there any other way i can check this?

I have searched a lot over internet but could not find the solution.
Seriously not getting a clue of how to get it done.

It would be great if anyone could guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://ruepprich.wordpress.com/2011/12/16/query-up-a-list-of-files-from-os-directory/) can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to do this by writing a java procedure, as described here by Tom Kyte:

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:439619916584

```
GRANT JAVAUSERPRIV to <your user>
/
create global temporary table DIR_LIST
( filename varchar2(255) )
  on commit delete rows
/
create or replace and compile java source named "DirList"
    as
    import java.io.*;
    import java.sql.*;

    public class DirList
    {
      public static void getList(String directory)
                       throws SQLException
      {
        File path = new File( directory );
        String[] list = path.list();
        String element;

        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        {
            element = list[i];
            #sql { INSERT INTO DIR_LIST (FILENAME)
                   VALUES (:element) };
        }
      }
    }
/
create or replace procedure get_dir_list( p_directory in varchar2 )
    as language java
    name 'DirList.getList( java.lang.String )';
/
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Davek. But i am asking for a way to get the timestamp of any file using PL/SQL. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: YOu wold call @davek 's java procedure from PL/SQL.  I don't think there is any way to get this attribute directly from PL/SQL.  I looked at the UTL_FILE package, and there is one function to get file attributes, but it only returns the size and # of blocks.

Comment: Found one way of doing it. We can write a unix shell script to get the timestamp of the file and after checking that we could call the oracle procedure as needed.                                  $file_ts = $(stat --printf=%y filename| cut -d. -f1);
$yesterday_ts = $current_timestamp - 86400;

if [ file_ts -gt $yesterday_ts ]; then
    sqlplus -s scott@SID/tiger<<END
    execute PROCEDURE_NAME;
    commit;
    exit;
fi

Answer (score 1):

Another approach might be to make use of the preprocessor directive for external tables.
Please have a look at Mr. Kyte's article in Nov/Dec 2012 Oracle Magazine. He is playing with unix df, you can play with unix ls or windows dir.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-nov/o62asktom-1867739.html

```
SQL> create table df
  2  (
  3   fsname   varchar2(100),
  4   blocks   number,
  5   used     number,
  6   avail    number,
  7   capacity varchar2(10),
  8   mount    varchar2(100)
  9  )
 10  organization external
 11  (
 12    type oracle_loader
 13    default directory exec_dir
 14    access parameters
 15    (
 16      records delimited
 17      by newline
 18      preprocessor
 19      exec_dir:'run_df.sh'
 20      skip 1
 21      fields terminated by
 22      whitespace ldrtrim
 23    )
 24    location
 25    (
 26      exec_dir:'run_df.sh'
 27    )
 28  )
 29  /
Table created.
```