# Calling Python from Oracle

Tags: python, sql, oracle, pandas, cx-oracle

Is it possible to call Python within an Oracle procedure? I've read plenty of literature about the reverse case (calling Oracle SQL from Python), but not the other way around.

What I would like to do is to have Oracle produce a database table, then I would like to call Python and pass this database table to it in a DataFrame so that I could use Python to do something to it and produce results. I might need to call Python several times during the Oracle procedure. Does anyone know if this is possible and how could it be done?

Comment: split your logic into smaller chunks and pass the results between the blocks of the python code, and so on

Comment: Utilizing the preprocessor directive might be a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17351109/995018

Comment: Other than PL/SQL, Oracle procedures can invoke methods written in [java classes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/data_access.htm#CNCPT1798).

Comment: why don't use cx_Oracle to get results from your procedure as output to be treated as dataframes using panda ? You could have everything in Python, and only using the procedure to get specific data sets. I have a procedure that returns a sys_refcursor as output, but the returns depends on how I call it. This result is used by cx_Oracle and Python poanda. During the process other calls are done to the same procedure to retrieve different sets of data. This way I combine powerful python functionality with the power of Oracle in create datasets fast where millions off rows are involved.

Answer (score 8):

On the edge there is a possibility on how to overcome the PL/SQL limitations.
You can design a specific interface between Database and Python program.
I suppose You'd use one of the Python's library to get some data from the Net.
And then exchange it's data with Oracle using the C Library.

call python using c library -> data file -> external table -> data

*NOTICE: Take it as a proof of concept or rather starting point for deeper exploration. Also I'd strongly discourage You from using it on production. Breaking the PL/SQL jail to call system program could be considered at least as unsafe.*

So this is the possible way on how to proceed:

**--== Prerequisities ==--**

pip install quandl

**--== quandl.py ==--**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import quandl
# World Bank Education Statistics
# Population, tertiary, total - Czech Republic
data = quandl.get("WEDU/CZE_SP_TER_TOTL_IN")
data.to_csv("/u01/data/data.txt")
```

**--== exec.c ==--**

```
//
// gcc -Wall -fPIC -c exec.c
// gcc -shared -o exec.so exec.o
// mkdir -p /u01/lib
// cp exec.so /u01/lib
//

#include <stdlib.h>

int execute() {
  system("/u01/bin/get_data.py");
  return 0; // We want to make the compiler happy
}
```

**--== LISTENER CONFIGURATION ==--**

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
...
  (SID_DESC =
...
    (ENVS="EXTPROC_DLLS=ANY")
    (PROGRAM = extproc)
...
```

**--== DDL PART ==--**

```
create or replace library c_exec is '/u01/lib/exec.so';

create or replace procedure exec as external
  name "execute"
  library c_exec
  language c;
/

create directory pydata as '/u01/data';

create table data (
  "date" varchar2(14),
  "value" varchar2(32)
) organization external (  
  type oracle_loader
  default directory pydata
  access parameters ( 
    records delimited by newline
    nobadfile nodiscardfile nologfile
    fields terminated by ','
   ) location (pydata:'data.txt')
  );
```

**---=== USAGE ===---**

*--== DOWNLOAD DATA FOR PROCESSING ==--*

Using the external PL/SQL C library You would call the python program that stores the result to the expected location for the external table.

```
execute exec;
```

*--== QUERY THE DATA ==--*

```
select 
  to_date("date",'yyyy-mm-dd') "date", 
  to_number("value") "value" 
from data 
  where "date" != 'Date';
```

**--== RESULT ==--**

```
date           value
--------- ----------
31-DEC-70     886414
31-DEC-71     885549
31-DEC-72     877533
31-DEC-73     862859
```

Answer (score 6):

You can [write stored procedures in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/chfive.htm) and you can [use Java to run Python code](http://www.jython.org/), so you can possibly combine the two to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the advice. I'm not too familar with Java and due to the time constraint, I probably will just do everything in Python. i.e use Python to run the sql part then carry on with the Python processing.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are a lot of different answers, with some very good options, but let me try to propose another one.

Let's imagine this scenario:

- I have a set of python programs that interact with data in different ways, you mentioned data frames.
- I have a big Oracle procedure that during runtime, needs to run the python scripts, so basically I need to use Python inside Oracle PL/SQL, which is not possible unless you use external libraries or Java code ( examples already provided )

What you can do always is calling SHELL SCRIPTS from `PL/SQL` using the API of `DBMS_SCHEDULER`. Those shell scripts can called whatever you want to, in this case Python programs.

My scenario is as follows:

- One Python program running the function to get the result set of a sys_refcursor variable.
- One Oracle Procedure calling those Python programs by a generic shell script

Let's make it work

```
SQL> create table t_python ( c1 number generated by default on null as identity ( start with 1 increment by 1 ) ,
                        c2 varchar2(10) ,
                        c3 date
                       ) ;             

Table created.

SQL> declare
begin
   for r in 1..10
   loop
      insert into t_python values ( null , dbms_random.string('A','5') , sysdate - round(dbms_random.value(1,100),0) );
          commit ;
   end loop;
end;
/  

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from t_python
  2  ;

        C1 C2         C3
---------- ---------- ---------
         1 Anrio      14-JUL-20
         2 ouaTA      04-MAY-20
         3 Swteu      06-JUL-20
         4 kdsiZ      24-MAY-20
         5 PXxbS      14-MAY-20
         6 xQFYY      18-JUN-20
         7 oahQR      09-MAY-20
         8 ZjfXw      24-MAY-20
         9 AmMOa      26-JUL-20
        10 IQKpK      25-JUL-20

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

So, lets imagine I have a function in the database that returns a `SYS_REFCURSOR` object, so a collection or dataset.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_result_table_f RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
   r_python SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   OPEN r_python FOR 
   SELECT 
      c1,
      c2,
      c3
   FROM 
      t_python 
    ORDER BY 
         c1,   
         c2,
         c3;

   RETURN r_python;
END;
/

Function created
```

If I call this function with my python program, it works perfect.

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd

conn = cx_Oracle.connect('user/pwd@hostname:port/servicename')
cur = conn.cursor()

refCursor = cur.callfunc('get_result_table_f', cx_Oracle.CURSOR, [])
for row in refCursor:
    print(row)

Result

$ /usr/bin/python3.6 /home/myuser/testcursor.py
(1, 'Anrio', datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 14, 12, 38, 52))
(2, 'ouaTA', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 4, 12, 38, 52))
(3, 'Swteu', datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 6, 12, 38, 52))
(4, 'kdsiZ', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 24, 12, 38, 52))
(5, 'PXxbS', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 14, 12, 38, 52))
(6, 'xQFYY', datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 18, 12, 38, 52))
(7, 'oahQR', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 9, 12, 38, 52))
(8, 'ZjfXw', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 24, 12, 38, 52))
(9, 'AmMOa', datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 26, 12, 38, 52))
(10, 'IQKpK', datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 25, 12, 38, 52))
```

So, how can I call this python program within my oracle procedure ?

Well, my option is using the API of DBMS_SCHEDULER, which only requires a shell script to invoke the python program. In order to setup `DBMS_SCHEDULER`, you onlz need to :

- Create a credential that the scheduler will use to run your shell. It must be an OS user ( In my example below is ftpcpl ).
- Use the scheduler job type EXTERNAL SCRIPT
- Use a Shell script to call the python program ( the python script must in the same server as the database. Is there an option for doing in another server, but it is more complicated because you need to install the Oracle scheduler agent )

This is how it should look like

```
create or replace procedure run_python_program 
as
v_job_count  pls_integer;
v_owner      varchar2(30);
v_job        varchar2(120) := 'MY_PYTHON_SCRIPT';
begin
    select count(*) into v_job_count from dba_scheduler_jobs where job_name = v_job ;
    if v_job_count > 0
    then
        DBMS_SCHEDULER.drop_job (job_name=> v_job , force => true);
    end if;

    DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job
    (
        job_name             =>  v_job,
        job_type             => 'EXTERNAL_SCRIPT',
        job_action           => '/home/myuser/my_shell_script.sh `date +%Y%m%d`',
        credential_name      => 'ftpcpl',
        enabled              =>  FALSE
    );
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.run_job (job_name=> v_job, use_current_session => true);
exception when others then raise;
end;
/
```

You shell script as easy as it seems

```
#/bin/bash 
odate=$1
logfile=/home/myuser/logfile_$odate.txt 
/usr/bin/python3.6 /home/myuser/testpython.py >> $logfile
```

Run the procedure

```
SQL> begin
     run_python_program; 
     end;
     /

 PL/SQL procedure successfully completed. 


 SQL> host cat /home/test/logfile_20200809.txt
    (1, 'Anrio', datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 14, 12, 38, 52))
    (2, 'ouaTA', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 4, 12, 38, 52))
    (3, 'Swteu', datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 6, 12, 38, 52))
    (4, 'kdsiZ', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 24, 12, 38, 52))
    (5, 'PXxbS', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 14, 12, 38, 52))
    (6, 'xQFYY', datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 18, 12, 38, 52))
    (7, 'oahQR', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 9, 12, 38, 52))
    (8, 'ZjfXw', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 24, 12, 38, 52))
    (9, 'AmMOa', datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 26, 12, 38, 52))
    (10, 'IQKpK', datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 25, 12, 38, 52))
```

### **SUMMARY**

Keep in mind that I did a very easy and simple test just to show you just how to call python ( embedded into shell script ) from PL/SQL. Actually, you can make the procedure to run several external scripts ( python programs ) and you can interact with the data in several ways.

For example, you could do this:

1. A procedure in Oracle creates data and stores this data in a table , collection or sys_refcursor object. I can call the python program within the PL/SQL using the DBMS_SCHEDULER EXTERNAL_SCRIPT job type and interact with the data.
2. The python generates a output data from the original dataset. Into the python program I can load the table or I can leave a csv as external table which I can read from the procedure back again.

And so on so forth.

I actually have a lot of programs in shell script which are being executed in steps using Oracle Scheduler Chains. One of those steps is actually a python program. I found the API of the `DBMS_SCHEDULER` quite useful when you need to run technologies out of PL/SQL, as long as they can be invoked using shell script ( or cmd in Windows ).

Comment: @user3311225 , using the `DBMS_SCHEDULER` package, you don't need Java or C or any other external language, You would only need a shell script to call your python programs.

Comment: my python script is returning a long string, how to insert the string in Oracle table? can you give example pls?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Preprocessor feature with external tables, which allows you to invoke a Python script to populate an external table with data. An example can be found in the Using External Table section of this OTN article: https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-994731.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on context you want to use Python you may consider **OML4Py**:

> [Oracle Machine Learning](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/datawarehouse-bigdata/machine-learning.html)
>
> Key benefits:
>
> *In-Database Processing: “Move the algorithms, not the data!”—Process data where it resides to eliminate data movement* and further leverage your Oracle environment as a high performance compute engine with parallel, distributed algorithms.
>
> Rapidly Deploy Machine Learning Applications—Because in-database machine learning models are native SQL functions, model deployment is immediate via SQL and R scripts.

---

Further reading:

[Oracle Machine Learning:  Scaling R and Python for the Enterprise](https://www.oracle.com/a/tech/docs/scaling-r-and-python-for-the-enterprise.pdf)

Slides(answering this particular question):

- page 7: Data access, analysis, and exploration
- page 24: Create
  user-defined functions from SQL (or use from R/Python)
- page 25:
  Invoke user-defined functions from SQL

[Oracle Machine Learning Platform  Move the algorithms,  not the data!](https://www.oracle.com/a/tech/docs/machine-learning/oracle-machine-learning-platform-overview.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is directly impossible because PL/SQL is specially designed for fast execution inside Oracle server and this isn't place where arbitrary code of other vendor is possible, due to internal limitations.

OTOH you can interact with another server from a stored procedure via TCP channels, [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_web.htm#i1006349) refers UTL_TCP package. In an external network server, you can utilize any language and any logic.

Answer (score 0):

kind of complicated but possible. I have seen it once. You need to

1. create a javaclass inside oracle database. This class calls a .py file in the directory which contains it.
2. create a procedure that calls the java class of item 1.
3. in your sql query, call the procedure of item 2 whenever you need it.