# Getting return value of python with oracle function

Tags: python, oracle

Is it possible create function in Oracle to get data from python code?

I created the Oracle function:

```sql
create or replace FUNCTION get_my_function_result
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS LANGUAGE PYTHON
NAME 'wrapper.call_my_function()';
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [Calling Python from Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22564503/1509264)